# onKeyDown and onChange with React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to assing an `onChange` and `onKeyDown` to an Input component with TypeScript and this is getting out of hand.

I have this `Input` component:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, KeyboardEvent } from 'react'

import { InputStyle } from './Input-style'

type InputProps = {
  name: string
  value: string | number
  type?: string
  placeholder?: string
  onBlur?: () => void
  onKeyDown?: (e: KeyboardEvent) => void
  onChange?: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

export const Input = (props: InputProps) => (
  <InputStyle
    type={props.type ? props.type : 'text'}
    name={props.name}
    id={props.name}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    value={props.value}
    onKeyDown={props.onKeyDown}
    onChange={props.onChange}
    onBlur={props.onBlur}
  />
)
```

Then I am using the component to do two things, validate that the keypress entered is a number and then add the value, and what seems to be an easy task is just giving me all sorts of TypeScript errors about the type

```
import React, { KeyboardEvent, ChangeEvent } from 'react'

export const renderInput = () => {
  const [rate, setRate] = useState<number>(0)

   
  // I want to add the value only if is a number and between 0-1 no letters
  const addRate = (e: KeyboardEvent | ChangeEvent) => {

    const element = e.target as HTMLInputElement
    const value = element.value

    if ('key' in e) {
      const reg = /[0-9]/
      // If is not a letter
      if (reg.test(e.key)) {
        // Add the value but here now it breaks 
        setRate(isNaN(value) || value > 1 ? 0 : value)
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Input
     type='number'
     name='Conversion Rate'
     value={rate === 0 ? '' : rate}
     placeholder='Percentage Decimal number'
     onKeyDown={addRate}
     onChange={addRate}
   />
  )
}
```

But at this point TypeScript errors with

> Argument of type 'string | 0' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'

I am really confused cause before trying to check for the keyDown it worked.

Comment: You would have had the same issues with JavaScript, they just would have been silent. TypeScript made the problem a lot more obvious.

Comment: But what is the problem? I just want an input to allow a number or float between 0-1

Comment: Check the answers, you're not parsing the string into a number, which your state variable expects.

Comment: If I add `parseFloat` then the input field just stops working completly with no errors

Comment: That's because the value is already set in the field, so the parse fails. Your field will still accept input but your code will stop setting the state.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `element.value` is of type string.

You can parse it to number with `parseInt(element.value)` or `+element.value`

That would be : `const value = +element.value`

Comment: The field stops working if I do that, and it only allows letters

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyDown` dispatches value as character. Therefore Typescript conflict types.

You can convert in `parseInt(value, 10)`.

You should note that field type number already accept only numbers and "e" of exponential.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me, they might sound right in principal, but it just conflicted one against each other as per my example. I was heading to TypeScript hell, so I got out of it by  using a regular text input and some regex:

```
const addRate = (val: string) => {
  // If it's a number and is higher than 1 exit
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(val)) && parseFloat(val) > 1) {
    return
  }

  // Regex to allow only decimal mumbers
  const reg = /^\d*(?:[.]\d*)?$/
  if (reg.test(val)) setRate(val)
}

<Input
  name='Conversion Rate'
  value={rate}
  placeholder='Decimal number - Optional'
  onChange={e => addRate(e.target.value)}
/>
```

No input type number, no keydown just regex

Comment: The initial parsing check is redundant. Just use the regex.

Comment: Also, this will still most likely give an error because your setRate() expects a number according to your `useState<number>(0)`

Comment: I changed that now is a string state it works with no errors and the initial check is needed cause it avoids letting numbers above 1

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the error is because fields in HTML always return text values, even when they're `type="number"` fields. In order to set the value in your state you need to first parse the string to an number or you'll get the type error you saw because your state is typed as a number.

```js
<Input
  type="number"
  value={rate}
  onInput={e => setRate(Number(e.target.value))}
/>
```

A number field will only allow valid numeric characters (including decimals and `e` for large exponentials). So you don't need to do all the validation in your code; Anything that the number field allows can be parsed by `Number()`.

Finally, always use `onInput` to capture input because this will also capture things like drag and drop, cut and paste, up/down arrows on a number field, etc.

**EDIT:** You said your comment you don't want the value to go above 1. You can set max and min values on a number field.

```html
<Input type="number" min="0" max="1" />
```

If you really need to clamp the value in code, the following will ensure that even values higher than 1 get clamped back down to 1.

```html
<Input
  onInput={e => setRate(Math.max(1, Number(e.target.value)))}
/>
```

Comment: I will give this a try  thanks, but I also needed to filter out anything greater than 1

Comment: Then put a `max` on your number field. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You see right here is where TypeScript starts throwing errors, my Input component does not have an `onInput` if I add it like this `onInput?: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void` I get `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

Comment: Also changing this to `onChange` which does not throw the error, does not work also, have you actually tried it? when you try to change the number it does not work at all it allow for multiple numbers above 1 and does not delete numbers

Comment: I can't speak to your component, but normal form `<input>` elements all have an `input` event (`onInput` in React) your can bind to. It is different from the change event in terms of when it fires.

Comment: You need to make sure any props on your wrapper component are passed to the inner `<input>` element so you can set a max. You're being foiled by this `<Input>` component.